# How to get the next element in an array with recursion?

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through an array with a recursive function, but I'm kinda stuck on how to do it.

What I want to achieve is this:

1. Get the first two arrays in `numbersArray`.
2. Get the first numbers in both arrays and add these together and then divide by 10.
3. Push the outcome into `sumOfNumbers`.
4. Get the next set of numbers and in `numbersArray` and repeat until all the numbers have been calculated.
5. Get the next set of two arrays in `numbersArray` and repeat.

This is what I  have now. It only gets the first element of an array:

```
function unitTest(block1, block2, result = []) {

let sumOfNumbers = []

let numbersArray = [
    [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
]

block1 = numbersArray[0][0]
block2 = numbersArray[1][0]

sumOfNumbers = (block1 + block2 ) % 10

result.push(sumOfNumbers)

console.log(sumOfNumbers)

console.log(result)

if (result.length == 10) {
  return result  
}else{
    // unitTest()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In recursion you need a base case and a recursive case. I put the whole array as a parameter and an index to know what item in the array we are processing. The stop recursion occurs when that index is greater than array. In recursive cases, we take 2 arrays and do the operations. Then, we call recursive the 2 next blocks

```
function unitTest(numbersArray, arrayIndex, result = []) {
    if (arrayIndex + 1 < numbersArray.length) {
      var block1 = numbersArray[arrayIndex]
    var block2 = numbersArray[arrayIndex + 1]

        for (var i = 0; i < block1.length; i++){
      sumOfNumbers = (block1[i] + block2[i]) % 10;

      result.push(sumOfNumbers);

      console.log(sumOfNumbers);
    }
    
    unitTest(numbersArray, arrayIndex + 2, result);
  } else {
      console.log(result);
  }
}

let sumOfNumbers = []

let numbersArray = [
    [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
]

unitTest(numbersArray, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, you are trying to compute the sum % 10 of each element of the array 0-1, 2-3, 4-5, ...

The usage of the recursion here is not necessary and a simple loop will do the job.

Here is the solution I could suggest

```
const numbersArray = [
  [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]
];

const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length - 1; i += 2) {
  const result = numbersArray[i].map((value, index) => {
    return (value + numbersArray[i + 1][index]) % 10;
  });
  results.push(result);
}

console.log(results);
```

The results constant is of type `number[][]` which contains the arrays of the computation for each pair of the original array.

Hope that will help you :)